# ARCORE: remove a specific renderable by clicking on this renderable

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I'm working on a project using Sceneform from ARCore. I develop it base on HelloSceneform example provided by ARCore.
What I wanna do is adding a renderable object by a hit and then delete it when I click on the specific renderable on the screen. 
I've tried method AnchorNode.setOnTapListener as following, but it didn't work(no response):

```java
anchorNode.setOnTapListener(new Node.OnTapListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onTap(HitTestResult hitTestResult, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                          if(anchorNode.getAnchor()!=null){
                              arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().removeChild(anchorNode);
                              anchorNode.getAnchor().detach();
                              anchorNode.setParent(null);
                          }
                      }
                  });
```

I also tried the following method, which causes unexpected close:

```java
      Scene scene = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene();
      scene.addOnPeekTouchListener(new Scene.OnPeekTouchListener() {
          @Override
          public void onPeekTouch(HitTestResult hitTestResult, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
              Node node = hitTestResult.getNode();
              node.setParent(null);
          }
      });
```

Is there any method could achieve this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below should detect the touch and delete the node.

If you want to have a separate button to delete a selected node you can add a regular button and listener and just use the 'touch' event to select the node you want to delete.

```js
private void handleOnTouch(HitTestResult hitTestResult, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"handleOnTouch");
        // First call ArFragment's listener to handle TransformableNodes.
        arFragment.onPeekTouch(hitTestResult, motionEvent);

        //We are only interested in the ACTION_UP events - anything else just return
        if (motionEvent.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            return;
        }

        // Check for touching a Sceneform node
        if (hitTestResult.getNode() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"handleOnTouch hitTestResult.getNode() != null");
            Node hitNode = hitTestResult.getNode();

            if (hitNode.getRenderable() == andyRenderable) {
                Toast.makeText(LineViewMainActivity.this, "We've hit Andy!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().removeChild(hitNode);
                AnchorNode hitNodeAnchor = (AnchorNode) hitNode;
                if (hitNodeAnchor != null) {
                     hitNode.getAnchor().detach();
                }
                hitNode.setParent(null);
                hitNode = null;
             }
        }
```

}

The above is extracted from various parts of a VR test application and combined here for a concise example - the full working application source is available here: https://github.com/mickod/LineView

Update - Kotlin version (tested April 2020):

```js
    private fun removeAnchorNode(nodeToRemove: AnchorNode) {
        //Remove an Anchor node
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().removeChild(nodeToRemove);
        nodeToRemove.getAnchor()?.detach();
        nodeToRemove.setParent(null);
        nodeToRemove.renderable = null
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused with hitNode().detach(); Is that a self-defined function?

Comment: @Ivana - apologies, that was a copy error - the project this is from is more complex so I extracted the key bits and renames some variable etc. Corrected above.

Comment: @Ivana - one other comment, its worth maybe making sure you have some logging so you can be sure your touch event is actually making it to the removal code. In other words to check that some previous listener for touch events has not consumed the touch event.

Comment: `hitTestResult.getNode()` returns just a Node and not an AnchorNode, and there is no `getAnchor()` function in Node. Is there a missing cast to AnchorNode or something?

Comment: @DanielO - Yes, good catch. The code is a shortened version from an example app so I've included the link to the full app source also, as its tested and working. The above code should have some checks and error logging added if being used also, but I'll leave it simple here.

Comment: Hello  I am trying to remove the node , but the last  node is not getting removed from the UI. Any ways to acheve that ?

Comment: @YeshaShah - it sounds like maybe there is some check for last node in your solution that is causing problems. If you look at the git repository above the solution there will remove the last node and should be possible to copy and modify for your needs/

Answer (score 0):

I know i am late but it may be helpful for someone.

1. Node you want to remove, first of you have to select that **Transferable node** by click or touch that node.
2. **TransfarableNode.setOnTapListener** this bulit in method serve purpose for us.
3. After that get node from **HitTestResult** and than detach node.

**Here is the code you can use for selecting and removing node.**

```
    transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode );
    transformableNode.setRenderable(model_nodeRenderable);
    transformableNode.select();
    transformableNode.setOnTapListener((HitTestResult hitTestResult, MotionEvent Event) ->
    {

       Node nodeToRemove = hitTestResult.getNode();
       anchorNode.removeChild(nodeToRemove );

    });
```