# How to drag and delete ARCore node in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I have problem, I want to drag and delete object in ArFragment. I have tried to add ontouchlistener to each node and ondraglistener to delete area. This is my code:

This is my touch listener

```
    override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() === MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            val data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "")
            val shadowBuilder = View.DragShadowBuilder(
                view
            )
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0)
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

This is my draglistener for delete area

```
internal class MyDragListener: View.OnDragListener {

    override fun onDrag(v: View, event: DragEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.getAction()) {
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
                v.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> v.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED -> v.visibility = View.GONE
            DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED -> v.visibility = View.GONE
            else -> {
            }
        }// do nothing
        return true
    }
}
```

this is my current delete node (all of the nodes)

```
fun removeAllSticker(fragment: ArFragment) {
        val nodeList = ArrayList(fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getChildren())
        for (childNode in nodeList) {
            if (childNode is AnchorNode) {
                if ((childNode as AnchorNode).anchor != null) {
                    (childNode as AnchorNode).anchor!!.detach()
                    fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().removeChild(childNode)
                    (childNode as AnchorNode).setParent(null)
                }
            }
        }
        cleanupFragment(fragment)
    }

    private fun cleanupFragment(fragment: ArFragment) {
        val scene = fragment.arSceneView.scene
        fragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(null)
        scene!!.removeOnUpdateListener{
            fragment.onUpdate(it)
        }
    }
```

Please help me, I'm stuck and already search on google

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple code snippet showing how to create and then delete a node:

```
AnchorNode anchorsNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
anchorsNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

Node holdNode = new Node();
holdNode.setParent(anchorsNode);
holdNode.setRenderable(yourModelRenderable);

holdNode.setOnTouchListener(new Node.OnTouchListener() {

    @override
    public boolean onTouch(HitTestResult hitTestResult, 
                             MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        anchorsNode.removeChild(holdNode);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use a sample code from **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811991/arcore-remove-a-specific-renderable-by-clicking-on-this-renderable)** post.

And if you wanna know how to drag a node in ARCore, please read **[this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5485-arcore-sceneform-sdk-getting-started)** RW post.

Comment: Thanks, the delete node working so well and I have implemented drag, but it seems draglistener is not working when I dragged the node to the certain place (image view) that I've defined before

Comment: Seems so. The problem is all the ARCore and Sceneform features are not-well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do that is using MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE in onTouchListener() or onPeekListener()

```
when (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(motion)) {
    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
        MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(motion).also { pointerIndex ->
            mLastTouchX = MotionEventCompat.getX(motion, pointerIndex)
            mLastTouchY = MotionEventCompat.getY(motion, pointerIndex)
        }
        mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(motion, 0)
    }
    MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
        val (x: Float, y: Float) =
            MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(motion, mActivePointerId).let { pointerIndex ->
                MotionEventCompat.getX(motion, pointerIndex) to
                        MotionEventCompat.getY(motion, pointerIndex)
            }
        marker?.node?.localPosition = Vector3(touchRightLeft+mPosX, initLocalPosition.y, touchTopBottom+mPosY)
        mLastTouchX = x
        mLastTouchY = y
    }
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID
    }
    MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> {
        MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(motion).also { pointerIndex ->
            MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(motion, pointerIndex)
                .takeIf { it == mActivePointerId }
                ?.run {
                    val newPointerIndex = if (pointerIndex == 0) 1 else 0
                    mLastTouchX = MotionEventCompat.getX(motion, newPointerIndex)
                    mLastTouchY = MotionEventCompat.getY(motion, newPointerIndex)
                    mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(motion, newPointerIndex)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

See also the official Android docs https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale?hl=zh-tw